# Rally SDK 2 grid hand-rolled links with target=_blank take me to a not-quite-blank page 

Tags: javascript, rally

When I make an sdk 2 grid and try to make the first column a link to the item's detail page with a target of _blank, clicking takes me to a window of just the Rally colors.  Like this:

[image: The Rally Livery]

I'm configuring using the renderer on the columncfgs:

```
columnCfgs: [
        {
          text: 'TestCase', dataIndex: 'FormattedID', width: 65,
          renderer: function(value,style,row_data, row_index){
                return Ext.String.format("<a target='_blank' href='/slm/detail/tc/{1}'>{0}</a>", value, row_data.data.ObjectID);
        }
    },
```

If I don't put _blank as a target, then it takes me to the right page, but shoved into the dashboard panel!

Answer (score 1):

This is currently how we make them (snippet from an XTemplate; values here would be your row_data.data):

```
<a href="{[Rally.util.Navigation.createRallyDetailUrl(values)]}" 
    target="_top">{FormattedID}</a>
```

We will be exposing some easier standard way to create defect links as we near the GA release of the 2.0 SDK.

Comment: Kyle,  What I'm having trouble with here is that the _top takes over the current page and I want to open a new window/tab.  But when I use _blank as a target, then I get that blank colored page -- and the console says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'session' of undefined".

Comment: What browser are you using?  If you right click the link and choose open in new tab does it show a similar error?